# Where can I get a frame for a 4x18" panoramic print?

Tags: panorama, prints, frames

I know a specialist framing shop can make custom frame sizes but are there any places that make this frame size as a pre-set item, for a panorama?

Comment: Flagged as 'too localized' as there are different answers depending on locale.

Comment: Google it for online options or go to any store that will custom make frames locally if they don't already carry your favorite size. This applies to every size, not just 4x18. I don't think we need every size under the sun asked here on this website, especially since we don't live in the same place.

Comment: I know you have your web site where you sell prints in odd sizes. Are you looking for a supplier for that? Maybe some further explanation in the question would help the naysayers here.

Comment: @mattdm,yes. Basically I sell 4x18" prints (without frames) and so customers regularly ask where they can buy frames. Google is a bit thin on results so I was hoping you bright people might have some clever ideas ;-)

Comment: I just did a 8x32" panorama which I made into a 10x34" framed print. The print cost less than $20 at Bay Photo and my local Hobby Lobby charged a total of around $50 for dry mount, matting, glass, and I assembled my own frame rails (as mentioned in comments below).

Answer (score 2):

You can get a frame intended for 3 landscape 4x6" photos and then get a bespoke mount.

I saw some Nielsen frames in UK shop called "Athena". They also cut the mounts for £5.

[image: panoramic picture frames]

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: I have done this approach with good success along with also finding low priced, pre-made, frames in such things as wall mirrors (removing the mirror glass of course). Wall mirrors also tend to be made in odd sizes and even found at places like garage/yard sales.

Answer (score 2):

Professional framing suppliers like [Pictureframes.com](http://www.pictureframes.com/) will sell you the components for whatever size you want. Metal frames are usually sold in pairs of sides, so for a 4x18" frame, you would order a 4" pair and an 18" pair. The sides are then easily assembled with hardware they provide. They will also cut glazing, backing, and matting to whatever size you need.

Comment: I really like my local Hobby Lobby or Michael's stores. They carry these frame sides in pairs as mentioned along with the other hardware. Albeit, you are very likely to find cheaper prices online, I also have Hobby Lobby do my dry mounting, matting and cutting of the glass. A total one-stop experience. To save some more cash, you can go to a home improvement store for the glass. They should even cut it down to size for you in store.

Answer (score 0):

If you google 4X18 frame, several results come up. Most are for the same brand name, Craig, and are fulfilled by Sears/K-mart.

http://m.kmart.com/productdetails.do?partNumber=021V003618448000P

http://www.sears.com/craig-frames-inc-4x18-custom-1.25inch-wide-complete/p-021V003601878000P

http://www.shopping.com/craig-frames-inc-4x18/DhVztcxF7HhULoCozz9gTQ==/info

http://shopping.aol.com/craig-frames-inc-4x18-custom-15-wide-black-wood-picture-frame-15driftwoodbk/pg879124738

If you want a frame large enough for a matte around your 4x18 photo, then you would of course need to find a larger frame. A two inch matte would require an 8x22 frame. A google search for "8x22 frame" yields results from the same sources as the 4x18 search.